# In sphinx how does the search result display if the index updates inbetween two setlimit calls

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I have just started working on sphinx with php. Was just wondering is if i set limit to 20 records per call.

```
$cl->SetLimits ( 0, 20);
```

the index recreate is say set to 5 minutes with a --rotate option.

So if in my application i have to call the next 20 search results i call the command

```
$cl->SetLimits ( 20, 20);
```

Suppose the index is recreated in between the two setlimit calls. And say a new document is inserted with say the highest weight. (and i am sorting results by relevance.)

Wouldnt the search result shift by one position down so the earlier 20th record will now be the 21st record and so i again get the same result at the 21st position that i got in the 20th position & so my application will display a duplicate search result. Is this true..any body else got this problem.

Or how should I overcome this?

Thanks!

Edit (Note: The next setlimit command is called based on a user event say 'See more Results')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that can happen.

But usually happens so rarely that nobody notices.

About the only way to avoid it would be to store some sort of index with the query. So as well as a page number, you include a last id. Then when on the second page etc, use that id to exclude any new results created since the search started.

On the first page query, you lookup the biggest id in the index, need to run a second query for that.

(this at least copes with new additions to the index, but its harder to cope with changes to documents, but can be done in a similar way)

Comment: Thanks! i will do what you suggested if i dont find a way... What is the average result limit i should set for a mobile app web service so that it is not very slow (to accommodate for network transit and searching time) suppose if i have 1 billion documents in sphinx with say only two string attributes and one string field(one/two sentences per field)

Answer (score 0):

setLimit sets the offset on the result server side, http://php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setlimits.php.

So to answer your question, no, it will query the with max_matches and save a result set, from there you work with the result set and not the indexed data.

One question though, why are you indexing it every 5 minutes? It would be better just to re-index every time your data changes.

Comment: Actually my web service creates a new Sphinx client object everytime  the user click on 'more results' and so i believe it uses a new resultset. How do i preserve the same object even if the user clicks on 'more results' (i.e. if in case i need to do say because it seems it is updating the search result with the new document inserted). What else i can do so that it uses the same resultset. (Also please note there are multiple users accessing the webservice. Sorry i am new to this.

Comment: i am indexing every 5 minutes since i think the data can change anytime and i was planning to keep it as realtime as possible (i am planning to include a main-delta scheme)

Comment: The documentations says: Sets offset into server-side result set and amount of matches to return to client starting from that offset (limit). Can additionally control maximum server-side result set size for current query (max_matches) and the threshold amount of matches to stop searching at (cutoff).

Comment: What if i run the script again based on a user event to get the next bucket of results. The script again creates a new sphinx object. How does the server recognize which resultset to pick from. Also till when does the resultset stay in the server`s memory ,does it purge after the web service script exits. Can i preserve this result set till the next time the user generates an event to get the next bucket of results. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but take a look at this : http://www.filedropper.com/sphinx it is a eBook pdf that I used for understanding and implementing Sphinx, they explain it in there

Comment: Do however note that is a pirated copy. For the real book see http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596809539.do